# Calling functions of a static member object in C++

Tags: c++, static-members

I'm not sure I've used the right terminology in my title, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a lightweight particle class (simplified) that requires random behavior for birth and wall-collision. I'd like to keep the facilities for that in the class itself. To my understanding a static member is created only once and can be shared among all instances of the class.

For the random number generator object, I would like to call the *seed* method once, but am unsure how to do this, as most examples use plain static variables or functions.

**Particle.h:**

```
#include <random>

class Particle
{
    public:
        Particle();
    private:
        static std::default_random_engine pRNG;
        static std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(0, 1);
};
```

**Particle.cpp**

```
#include "particle.h"
#include <ctime>

std::default_random_engine Particle::pRNG.seed(time(NULL)); // <- wrong, help!

Particle::Particle() {}

// methods, etc.
```

Putting the *seed* method into the Particle constructor would call it on every born particle I suppose. The only quick hack I could think of was to add a bool member to the Particle class, that is set to false on the first seed call.

Comment: Make a `ParticleRGN` class which has only one instance of itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to do this: Make a class called "AutoInitRNG", which seeds the `default_random_engine` in its constructor. And make that class a static member variable of Particle. Something like this:

```
class AutoInitRNG
{
public:
    std::default_random_engine pRNG;

    AutoInitRNG()
    {
        pRNG.seed(time(NULL));
    }
};

class Particle
{
//...
private:
    static AutoInitRNG RNG;
};
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I picked Taylor's answer as it was the easiest for me to grasp and implement. I added the simple _RNG_ class in _Particle.h_ and made that a static member (_static RNG pRNG_) of Particle. In Particle.cpp I defined _RNG Particle::pRNG_ at the top.

Comment: @Adrian Just be cautious if you do this for multiple classes. The order/time of static initialization is largely up to the compiler, so you could run into weird behavior caused by two classes getting the exact same seed value. Has happened to me before.

Answer (score 0):

> std::default_random_engine Particle::pRNG.seed(time(NULL)); // <- wrong, help!

This is perfectly fine, except that its in the wrong place. it should be inside a code block, context of some kind. I suggest to separate this facility to a singleton class, that would be called for random number. Otherwise, you'll have to call it from outside the class somewhere.

Calling it in a constructor will lead to multiple calls, that's not what you want, or if you want to call it from within a class - add a static flag to mark that it has been seeded to make sure you only call it once.

Answer (score 0):

You want to call `seed` after the construction of `Particle::pRNG`, and exactly once.  Anything with static storage duration is initialized exactly once.  And if two definitions with static storage duration and dynamic initialization are in the same translation unit, they'll always be initialized in that order (and destroyed in the reverse order).

So all you need is a second definition.  The trick is making up something just so you can define it.

```
// In header:
class Particle {
    // ...
private:
    static std::default_random_engine pRNG;
    class RNG_Setup_;
    friend class Particle::RNG_Setup_;
};

// In source:
std::default_random_engine Particle::pRNG;
class Particle::RNG_Setup_ {
    RNG_Setup_() { Particle::pRNG.seed(time(nullptr)); }
    static RNG_Setup_ setup_instance;
};
Particle::RNG_Setup_::setup_instance{};
```